# Cypress - "logout" API call not being recognized

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, cypress

The site I am writing a test for (https://www.songtrust.com) has a logout action that is handled via an API.

I have a simple test which partially performs the following:

```
it('Logout', () => {
  //click the left nav
  cy.get('.fa-bars').click()
  //click the logout link
  cy.get('#logout-submit').click()
})
```

The "logout" link in the menu has the following href:

```
<a id="logout-submit" href="#" class="action">LOGOUT</a>
```

Clicking the link triggers an API call to `http://app.songtrust.com/api/v1/user/logout/`.  On a successful response the site then responds by deleting the users session cookie and redirecting them to the sites homepage.

js on the page that handles this action:

```
$('#logout-submit').on('click', function () {
  stlib.api(stlib_api_url + 'user/logout/', {}, 'GET', go_home, go_home)
})
```

Also some python code that deletes the session cookie:

```
def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
            response = self.create_response(request, {'success': True})
            response.delete_cookie('logged_in_state')
            return response
```

Cypress is handling the href in the anchor tag in the following way:

[image: Request after clicking logout link]

As you can see, I click the #logout-submit element, which correctly triggers the API call to the "logout" endpoint.  The URL then resolves to `https://app.songtrust.com/dashboard/#`, basically appending the hash to the end of the page I was currently on.  Things get stuck from that point.  The expected redirect isn't triggered, and the page is stuck loading until cypress times out.  I believe it is successfully killing the session by deleting the cookie before things get "stuck".

This of course works as expected when performed manually within the Cypress browser window.

Is there some way to handle this I'm not considering, or is this just a gap within the Cypress tool I need to work around?  I'm fairly new to Cypress, so any guidance that can be provided would be much appreciated.

Comment: After logout is clicked you can add a test to check the url change `cy.url().should('include', '<home_page_url>') `. Refer https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html#Examples. Since you did not add an 'expect' after clicking 'logout', the test ends there.

Comment: The issue is the expected redirect is never initiated.  The assertion simply fail.  My question is, why only during the script execution isn't the page redirecting as expected?  This is behavior that works outside of Cypress.

Comment: Try force click, it might not clicking it even though it says that is clicked.

Comment: The cypress team has noted this as a potential bug.  I am following up with their support folks.